# Annuities with payments in geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, finance, actuarial-science, geometric-progressions

I am having trouble understanding how to solve problems with varying annuities. There is this problem I was given as a homework which I can't figure out.

> Barry presently has 2.9 million dollars in an account paying a nominal
>   rate of 6.6 percent convertible quarterly. He plans to start making
>   quarterly withdrawals from the account when he retires, the first
>   coming in exactly 20 years. If he would like to be able to make 88
>   withdrawals (with the last emptying the account) and the withdrawals
>   will increase by 1.2 percent from one to the next, how large is his
>   first withdrawal?

In the solution, I used the formula for payments varying in geometric progression, where R is the amount of the first withdrawal:
$$
PV =R \frac{1-(\frac{1+k}{1+i})^n}{i-k}
$$

Interest rate is convertible quarterly, so the annual effective interest rate is

$$(1+\frac{0.066}{4})^4-1=0.06765$$

For PV I have

$$2,900,000(1.06765)^{4*19}=10,059,099.498
$$

After putting everything into the formula and solving for R, I get
$$
10,059,099.498=R \frac{1-(\frac{1+0.012}{1+0.06765})^{88}}{(0.06765-0.012)}
$$
$$
R=\frac{10,059,099.498}{17.8078}=564,870.42
$$

But that is not correct answer.
I also tried to put $(4*20)$ instead of $(4*19)$ or $\frac{88}{4}$ instead of $88$ and so on, but the answer is still incorrect.

Maybe I should use another approach, but I don't have other ideas on how to solve it.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: The question of [spaceisdargreen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/397125/spaceisdarkgreen) is still pending.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't know the correct answer, since it is an online homework and when I submitted the number I got, it just said it's incorrect and didn't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Write out the cash flow.  Let $PV = 2.9 \times 10^6$ be the present value, $K$ be the amount of the first withdrawal, and let $j = i^{(4)}/4 = 0.066/4$ be the effective quarterly rate of interest.  Then
$$PV = Kv^{20} + (1.012)Kv^{21} + (1.012)^2 Kv^{22} + \cdots + (1.012)^{87} K v^{107},$$ where $v = 1/(1+j)$ is the effective quarterly present value discount factor.  Equivalently, we may write this as
$$(1.012)^{20} PV = (v')^{19} K \left(v' + (v')^2 + (v')^3 + \cdots + (v')^{88}\right)$$ where $v' = 1.012v$ can be regarded as an adjusted quarterly present value discount factor.  Consequently, $$K = \frac{(1.012)^{20} PV}{(v')^{19} a_{\overline{88}\rceil j'}} = \frac{1.012PV}{v^{19}} \frac{j'}{1 - (v')^{88}}$$ where $j' = 1/v' - 1$.  All that is left is to substitute the values into this expression, which gives $K = \$55096.90$.